# C#/WinForms: Sets and Gets Value of Static Variable

Tags: winforms, class, static

I have the following Global class file:

Global.cs

```
public static class Global
    {
        private static string _globalVar = "";

        public static string GlobalVar
        {
            get { return _globalVar; }
            set { _globalVar = value; }
        }
    }
```

I set the new value of string GlobarVar in Form1.cs as '1234'.

Form1.cs

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Global.GlobalVar = "1234";
        }
```

I tried to display the value to Form2.cs using the message box

```
public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show(Global.GlobalVar); // displays blank values
        }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please use the debugger.  Set breakpoints on the getter and setter so you *know* what's going on instead of guessing at it.

Answer (score 1):

Four  options:

- You're not constructing `Form1` before you construct `Form2`
- Something else is setting `Global.GlobalVar` back to null or an empty string
- Your forms are in different app domains, so they'll have entirely separate Global types
- You're running the application twice; static variables don't live on across different processes

It's hard to tell which of these is the case, but personally I'd try to avoid using global state to start with. It's a pain for testability and reasoning about how your program works.

Comment: Or maybe you are calling Form1() after Form2().

Comment: @PetriucFlorin: Will edit that in as part of the first bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Try your property page (file Global.cs) like these:

```
public class Global
{
    private static string _globalVar;

    public string GlobalVar
    {
        get { return _globalVar; }
        set { _globalVar = value; }
    }
}
```